How to move a set of local commits from one existing branch to another existing branch?
I have following situation in my local Git repository. I have switched to a wrong feature branch and there I have done a serie of commits. These commits haven't been pushed yet.
As soon as I have found that I have commited to a wrong feature branch I wanted to correct my mistake and move the commits to the correct feature branch. I am not sure whether cherry-picking is the correct method. Please can you tell me what is the most correct method for moving these commits from the wrong feature branch to the correct feature branch? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Generally, you could cherry pick the entire range of commits.  There are tons of questions on this site already which detail how to do that.
